# Infopath form people picker help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, forms-services, infopath-rules

I have an infopath form with a people picker that has multiple selection enabled.

What I want to achieve is to be able to split the accountid selected into multiple textboxes.

Currently I can get the multiples accountids and show them this way

i:0#.f|membership|alexd@zamproject.onmicrosoft.com;i:0#.f|membership|garthf@zamproject.onmicrosoft.com; using this function:

eval(eval(Person, 'concat(pc:AccountId, ";")'), "..")

From the above how can I for instance further break down the values to put alexd@zamproject.onmicrosoft.com in one text field and garthf@zamproject.onmicrosoft.com in another text field.

Thanks